# Using keyframes to create cyclic animation

Tags: html, css

I am working on a CSS only slider. However I don't have much experience with using keyframes.

I found this pen; could someone explain to me how the keyframes ensure that the animation runs in a cyclic manner rather than at the same time (where all the slides would disappear and reappear together)?

[Code pen link](http://codepen.io/davidhc/pen/nLpJk)

```css
.slider {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slide1,
.slide2,
.slide3,
.slide4,
.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371566801_p17tbs0rrjqdt1u4dnk94fe4b63.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade 8s infinite;
}
.slide2 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371565525_p17tbqpu0d69c21hetd77dh483.jpeg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade2 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade2 8s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371564896_p17tbq6n86jdo3ishhta3fv1i3.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade3 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade3 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes fade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide1'></div>
  <div class='slide2'></div>
  <div class='slide3'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this can be made a lot shorter using the `animation-delay` property of by making full use of the `animation` property shorthand.

Comment: @ILoveCSS That is a good point, you would then be able to get away with just the one `fade` animation.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? Please consider leaving feedback if you have any further questions or marking an answer as accepted if it addressed your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the each slide using a different keyframe, i.e. `slide1` uses `fade`, `slide2` uses `fade2` and `slide3` uses `fade3`. These keyframes all last 8 seconds however the frame in which the slide is shown is different:

- `slide1` is shown at 0% (0 seconds)
- `slide2` is shown at 33.333% (about 2.6 seconds)
- `slide3` is shown at 66.666% (about 5.3 seconds)

This particular method will work when you have three slides but would need to be adapted if you were to have a different amount. For example with four you would need to add an extra step to the keyframe:

```css
.slider {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slide1,
.slide2,
.slide3,
.slide4,
.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371566801_p17tbs0rrjqdt1u4dnk94fe4b63.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade 8s infinite;
}
.slide2 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371565525_p17tbqpu0d69c21hetd77dh483.jpeg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade2 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade2 8s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371564896_p17tbq6n86jdo3ishhta3fv1i3.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade3 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade3 8s infinite;
}
.slide4 {
  background: red;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade4 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade4 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes fade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes fade4 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide1'></div>
  <div class='slide2'></div>
  <div class='slide3'></div>
  <div class='slide4'></div>
</div>
```

As suggested by @ILoveCSS this code can be shortened to just the one keyframe animation by adding a third property to the `animation` property. This value is the `animation-delay` property and will stall the animation by the specified time:

```css
.slider {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slide1,.slide2,.slide3,.slide4,.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371566801_p17tbs0rrjqdt1u4dnk94fe4b63.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 8s infinite;

} 
.slide2 {
  background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371565525_p17tbqpu0d69c21hetd77dh483.jpeg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade 8s infinite 2.6s;
-webkit-animation:fade 8s infinite 2.6s;
}
.slide3 {
    background: url(http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/40946/580x0-9_cropped_1371564896_p17tbq6n86jdo3ishhta3fv1i3.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade 8s infinite 5.3s;
-webkit-animation:fade 8s infinite 5.3s;
}
@keyframes fade
{
  0%   {opacity:1}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 0}
  100% { opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide3'></div>
  <div class='slide2'></div>
  <div class='slide1'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good stuff, Thanks for explaining it so well.  +1

Comment: Thanks @ILoveCSS. Props to you for the comment on using `animation-delay` as it is a tidier method of achieving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think what he is trying is:

```
@keyframes fade
{
  0%   {opacity:1}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 0}
  100% { opacity: 1}
}
```

in this case slide1 is getting visible at the start of the animation and stops when it reached 33.333% and 66.666% and starts to visible at the end of the animation which is 100%.

```
@keyframes fade2
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 1}
  66.666% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

in the second slide2 at the start of the animation is not showing because slide1 is in the playing of it's animation and when slide1 reaches 33.333% started to stop and slide2 will start to fadeIn.

```
@keyframes fade3
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 1}
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

in the third slide3 the animation start to fadeIn at 66.666% because at this percent slide2 is in fadeOut state and it continue like this infinitely...

Hope you have an idea.